# java format string printing unable to print

Tags: java

I'm unable to run the code, it says it cannot resolve println with the parameters.

```
public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println("%s : %d", this.getName(), i);
        }
    }
```

Comment: `System.out.println` only supports complete values. You probably want `System.out.printf`. I'd add a '%n' to the format to add a new line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`System.out.println` just prints, literally, a string, and then prints a newline.

You want `System.out.printf`, which prints 'format strings' as you're using here. Note that it does not print newlines. Just add `\n`, `%n` doesn't really do what you think it does (it would print e.g. `\r\n` on windows. This is unneccessary and sometimes even actively harmful, hence, don't do that unless you really know you need it. You need it if you're emitting text files that need to look good when opened with notepad.exe. That's... about the one and only thing on the planet that requires \r\n to function. Everything else either accepts both \r\n, or only accepts \n, hence, just.. write \n, not %n).

Thus:

```
System.out.printf("%s : %d\n", this.getName(), i);
```

Comment: I wouldn't say that using `%n` is bad. If it's just for logging then it doesn't really matter. If you need to interact with other systems (through a network or files) then it is indeed better to use an explicit line ending, to prevent any odd behaviour if the code is migrated from one machine to another.

Comment: Isn't `println` equivalent to `line.separator` which is equivalent to `%n` shown in docs [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println())? I understand you want `/n` in some cases but if he was already using `println` I do not see how it would be relevant to his current situation.

Comment: In the absence of specific info, it's 95% `%n`/`\n` don't matter, 4% `\n` is better and 1% `%n` is better, roughly. That means that `%n` in a general tutorial is just wrong, given that it's exactly equally long and, if anything, `\n` requires less knowledge/reading of docs than `%n` to boot. It's nuanced and certainly not worth filing bugs for or whatnot, but, nevertheless. `\n` over `%n` unless you have specific needs. I'd say `System.out.println("X")` over `System.out.print("X\n")` - readability trumps the extremely small chance `\n` is statistically very slightly less likely to be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

That is because there is no `println()` method that takes a format string and substitution parameters.

There is the `format()` [method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintStream.html#format(java.util.Locale,java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...)) though (when using that, remember that you have to add the newline char in the line yourself).

Where: the real answer is ... in programming, **every** character matters. Meaning: you have to be **really** diligent about such things. Always read the javadoc carefully, and when you are taught: "there is no such method", then: look at the javadoc for the class you intend to use. Ensure that the method you want exists, and then ensure that the arguments you provide to it are matching the documented method signature.

Answer (score 2):

`System.out.println` does not support format parameters.  You can either use `System.out.printf` to immediately format and then print or format it with `String.format` which will give you a `String` result that you can then print or store into a variable.

`System.out.printf` example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        System.out.printf("%s : %d%n", this.getName(), i);
}
```

You would need to add `%n` to the formatting in order to print on new lines shown above.

`String.format` example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    System.out.println(String.format("%s : %d", this.getName(), i));

    //can also create a String variable with the result
    String formattedStr = String.format("%s : %d", this.getName(), i);
    //do whatever you want with the String
}
```

You would not need to add `%n` in this case because `println` will add the new line.